# Install Bootstrap 4 on Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, bootstrap-4

I have followed the following instruction in order to install Bootstrap 4 alpha on my Laravel 5.3 project, but it pops up errors.

Steps to install:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3 --save-dev
```

resources/assets/sass/app.scss

```
// change this line
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
//to this
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

resources/assets/sass/variables.scss

```
// change this line to rem or em units, or just remove it entirely
$font-size-base: 14px;
```

resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
// change this line
require('bootstrap-sass');
// to this
require('bootstrap');
```

I got the following error

> ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\resources\assets\js'  @
>   ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js 11:0-20  @
>   ./resources/assets/js/app.js

And I refresh my page and got this for console log

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bootstrap"
>       at webpackMissingModule (eval at  (app.js:89), :11:65)
>       at eval (eval at  (app.js:89), :11:151)
>       at Object. (app.js:89)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at eval (eval at  (app.js:228), :1:1)
>       at Object. (app.js:228)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at app.js:64
>       at app.js:67

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone who can fix this please?

Comment: excuse me, do you have elixir installed?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i reinstall alpha.5 and it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but I eventually try to reinstall alpha.5 by `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5 --save-dev` and it fixed the problem.